# After word break, align next line to the left rather than center

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break, text-styling

I am styling my paragraphs and I have line break after a certain amount of characters. I want to be able to make the line after the break to be aligned left rather than center.

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hello, my name is Taylor and welcome to my personal website!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: text-align:left then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `text-align-last`

> The text-align-last CSS property describes how the last line of a block or a line, right before a forced line break, is aligned.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last)</sup>

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.paragraph {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 220px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-align-last: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hello, my name is Taylor and welcome to my personal website!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.justify {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.paragraph {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 220px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class='justify'>
  <p class="paragraph">Hello, my name is Taylor and welcome to my personal website!</p>
</div>
```